# Road network distance from incident to facility

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have two sets of location shapefiles; one for incident and another for facility. I also have a road/street shapefile. I want to calculate the road/driving distance from each incident to every facility.

For example:

```
Incidents: A, B, C, D  
Facility: 1, 2, 3, 4
```

I want a result as follows:

```
Incident    Facility    Distance
A           1           1 mile
A           2           0.5 mile
A           3           2 mile
A           4           0.5 mile
B           1           3 mile
B           2           0.5 mile
B           3           4 mile
B           4           0.5 mile
```

Is it possible using ArcMap 10.2.2 if yes how?

Comment: If you are unable to obtain an ArcGIS for Desktop solution then, as per the [Tour], the place to ask about R as an alternative will be in a second question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will use network analyst to do this.  You will create a roadnetwork first with your road dataset.  Set up your parameters such as cost and accumulation. Then you will solve a closest facility problem.  Load your stopping points as your orders, and your starting points as your facilities and then solve.  When you examine the routes in the TOC you will find your distance.

A complete tutorial can be found here that explains everything you could ever want to know about network analyst.  You should be able to figure out everything you want with it, but if you have a specific question I would be glad to help.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/pdf/network-analyst-tutorial.pdf